# Redraw issues in SWT Canvas

Tags: java, canvas, swt, refresh

I am displaying a sequence of images in **SWT Canvas** using a **TimerTask** to redraw to the canvas every 5 seconds. It all works well but when I move some window over the canvas area, it starts getting all messy before it moves to the next image in sequence. Can I avoid this ?

This is the Canvas

> cnvs = new Canvas(customContainer,SWT.NO_REDRAW_RESIZE|
>   SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED);

I am drawing the image inside the paint listener this way

> int index=0;
>                         if(curImg>=0&&curImg<3)
>                            curImg++;
>                        else 
>                            curImg=0;
>
> ```
>                   Image img = imgs[curImg];
>
>                   if(curImg==3){
>                       index=curImg-1;
>                       img=imgs[index];
>                   }
> ```

```
e.gc.drawImage(img,
               0,
               0,
               img.getImageData().width,
               img.getImageData().height,
               0,
               0,
               cnvs.getSize().x,
               cnvs.getSize().y);
```

TimerTask function:

```
public TimerTask startTask() {
        return new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if(!UIManager.getShell().getDisplay().isDisposed()){
                UIManager.getShell().getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        if(!cnvs.isDisposed())
                        cnvs.redraw();

                    }
                });
            }
            }
        };
    };
```

and this is how it's invoked

> timer=new
>   Timer();                              timer.schedule(MainUI.compositeInstallationProgresslatest.startTask(),1000,5000);

Thanks for ur help !

Comment: Can you post a complete example that we can try out ourselves?

Comment: Ok. Strangely this issue is observed only on Win7 but not on Mac/Ubuntu.

Comment: Doesn't matter, please post an example.

Comment: I've updated the code snippets for your reference.

Comment: Tested it on Windows 7 and it looks just fine. Nothing messy anywhere.

Comment: Actually I forgot to share this code which I write before drawing the image in the paint listener, I've updated it.

Comment: Nope, still works fine

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51730/discussion-between-abbas-and-baz)